# Changing the resolution on my desktop changes the actual size of the screen displayed?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, resolution

I have a Dell S2716DG 1440p Monitor with G-Sync and a 1080 ti. It is running the latest Windows 10 Creators Update.

I noticed earlier today that the screen is not totally being used. There are about 20-40 pixels on the top, left, right, and about 10px on the bottom that are not used.

It looks like this (stackoverflow will not load the properly rotated photo):

[image: space between screen 1]

The resolution is set to native in Nvidia Experience, (2560x1440) but when I change the resolution, rather than making everything bigger but keeping the scale of the monitor, it actually uses less of the monitor itself.

Here's what that looks like:

[image: larger space between screen]

I have restored the monitor to factory settings and this did not resolve the issue.

I have reinstalled the Nvidia driver (v381.65). This did not work.

I have enabled "Resize the desktop" in the Nvidia Control Panel and the tool would not let me expand the screen beyond the bounds.

I have changed the Aspect Ratio in Nvidia Control Panel from Aspect Ratio (default) to Fullscreen, and then no scaling. These did not resolve the issue.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an option for underscan/overscan in the monitor itself?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I don't see something like that in the monitor settings.

Comment: Do you use HDMI or DVI to connect to monitor? I had a similar issue (with a Samsung FullHD), solved using DVI cable instead of HDMI.

Comment: I'm using a Display Port cable

Comment: @DCIndieDev, consider the option of using another type of port and cable, to see if something changes, or ask Dell support.

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of behaviour (letterboxing the screen when running at lower-than-native resolution) be _preferable_ compared with the alternative (severely distorting and blurring everything on the screen in order to force it to fill the entire monitor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my issue, I had to change the `Scaling` setting under `Adjust Desktop Size and Position` in the *Nvidia Control Panel* from "Aspect Ratio" to "Full Screen".

After this, I could change the resolution in the `Change Resolution` section of the Control Panel properly.

Its possible that the `Aspect ratio` option would scale properly if given resolutions that scale 1:1 with my monitor resolution. Non-scaling resolutions would still present black space on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go to your NVIDIA Control Panel (for ATI users, it's the Catalyst Control Center) and look for an "overscan / underscan" slider. Then adjust until your image fits your screen.

Comment: I'm not seeing an overscan or underscan, but I did find "Adjust desktop size and position" which gives me the options of Aspect Ratio, Full Screen, or Scaling. None had an effect. I also found "Enable Desktop resizing" but the tool did not allow me to expand my monitor beyond the margins